# Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I keep getting an error message.

```
<?php

mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db("account");

?>
```

Here is the error message I get when I try to load it in the browser:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebsite\TechanexSiteBase\connect.php on line 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Complete Guide**

**Note** :

- With mysqli you can specify the **Database Name** in `mysqli_connect()`
- You have to use `mysqli_connect_error()`, `not mysqli_error()`, to get the
  error from `mysqli_connect()`, because the latter requires you to supply
  a valid connection.

  ```
  <?php

      // Creating a database connection

      $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "databse_name");
      if (!$connection) {
          die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }


      // Selecting a database 

      $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "databse_name");
      if (!$db_select) {
          die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }

  ?>
  ```

Just do copy and paste & Then change the database name

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Answer (score 2):

The question body makes no sense, as the code is inconsistent with the error message. For the code present, the error message would have been `Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given`.

That aside, it seems this question attracts many visitors who are genuinely getting the error from the question title. For them, here is a complete and **proper** guide on [How to connect using mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect):

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, $charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
```

By following this routine, one would **never ever get an error** like this. As well as **many other errors** that would be induced by the code suggested in the other answers.

Important advantages of this code are

- as you can see, there is **no need** to `call mysqli_select_db()` function at all, as the database name could be supplied already in `mysqli_connect()`.
- the proper **error reporting** mode is set, and therefore the **actual error message** will be reported, explaining why `mysqli_connect()` returned `null`, hence you'll be able to fix the error.
- the proper **charset** must be always set
- and the **connection error** should be handled properly. Some mysqli internals is not what you really want for the **site visitors to see**.

The detailed explanation of all these issues could be found in the article linked above.

Answer (score 1):

You can establish your connection by a single line as follows.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","account");
?>
```

Here, localhost=server address; root=user name; ""=password; account=your database name.

or

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","account");
?>
```

There is also another way like you tried:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", ""); //connection
mysqli_select_db($con, "account"); //Mysqli_select_db() function expects exactly 2 parameters.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your db name into `mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "account");` as fourth element

Answer (score -1):

Yuu can create mysqli connection as follows:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You should not mix OOP and function-based approaches

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)